# Can the length of zigzag of the resistor be extended using circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[straight voltages]

    \draw(0,0)to[R,l_=$R$,*-*](4,0);

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Currently the above diagram has the 6 apexes of the resistor however what I want to do is to increase the number of it.

Is it able to be done using circuitikz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `resistors/zigs=6` (default `3`).  See manual, "3.5.3 Resistive components customization".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,1.5) to[R, l=$R$] ++(4,0);
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=1.5}
\draw (0,-0) to[R, l=$R$] ++(4,0);
\ctikzset{resistors/zigs=6, resistors/scale=.75,
  resistors/width=1.6}
\draw (0,-1.5) to[R, l=$R$] ++(4,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]